# Array list code in java not working

Tags: java

Hello guys I am trying to write an array list of strings with not specified size, I am setting a for loop with a sentinel to control the amount of input, but it seems not to work, this is the piece of cod that has the problem I think, Pleasse help !

```
    public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();

    String string;
    String string2;
    char[] string1=new char[1];
    char c;

    for(int i=0;!"null".equals(a.get(i));i++)
    {   
        string=input.nextLine();
        a.add(i,string);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give a detailed description of the problem - "it seems not to work" is *not* a detailed description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are getting an error.  I suggest you read the error and if you don't understand it, you should search for it or include it in the question.

In this case, your test is broken.  You don't have either a `null` value or `"null"` (which is not the same thing) in fact you don't have an element `0` which is why it is throwing an exception.

A simple solution is to check what you reading as you read it.

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
while(input.hasNext())
    a.add(input.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

`!"null".equals(a.get(i))` will just check if the string returned by `a.get(i)` does not equal `"null"`. I think what you wanna do is check `a.get(i) == null`, which will not work since requesting an item from a List that is at an index that is bigger than the list's size will throw a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To properly iterate over a `List`, use a foreach loop:

```
for(Object o : list) {
    //Execute your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the part where I have to get a false value by !"null".equals(a.get(i)) is not working like it should because the program does not get out of the loop